# android: position a textview below another textview

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

How to set texView2 below textView1?
I want to add second text view below first text view.

I tried this Layout Code below:

```
  <LinearLayout  
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingTop="8dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
                        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="UserID"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                        android:text="User name"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/button1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:background="#FFFFFF"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:text="Add Friend"
                        android:textColor="#0099CC" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

any help would be appreciated...

thank you...

Comment: The `layout_below` attribute is for `View` inside a `RelativeLayout`. You currently have a `LinearLayout` as the root.

Comment: textview is wrap content and your linear layout has horizontal oriantation

Comment: LinearLayout doesn't work like a relativeLayout so adding android:layout_below doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

use Relative Layout rather than Linear layout Or Set Linear Layout Orientation Vertical.

Using Relative Layout your Code Should like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   android:text="UserID"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="User name"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:text="Add Friend"
    android:textColor="#0099CC" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Or use LinearLayout Set Orientation To vertical if you want all Item Below one another than: your Code should be.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       android:text="UserID"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

       android:text="User name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />
      </LinearLayout>
      <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Add Friend"
        android:textColor="#0099CC" />
     </RelativeLayout>
```

read this artical for linear layout and relative layout

[LinearLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html)

[RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the orientation of linearLayout to vertical and its go

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="UserID"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="User name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="Add Friend"
        android:textColor="#0099CC" />
```